# How to update a LinkedList value stored in cache using Guava's LoadingCache

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, linked-list, guava

I am trying to utilize `LoadingCache` from the Guava library to cache a `LinkedList`.

```
LoadingCache<Integer, LinkedList<String>> cache;
```

I've setup a `CacheLoader` to handle misses, which is working fine. However there is another system that needs to submit updates to existing cache entries. Each update needs to be appended to the `LinkedList` and will arrive at a fairly quick rate (thousands per minute). Finally, it needs to be thread safe.

Here is a naive approach that illustrates the logic but is not thread safe:

```
public void add(Integer key, String value) {
    LinkedList<String> list = cache.get(key);
    list.add(value);
    cache.put(key, list);
}
```

Any advice on how to make this work? I can look at other libraries but Guava 14 is already a dependency of this codebase and would be very convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line in

```
public void add(Integer key, String value) {
    LinkedList<String> list = cache.get(key);
    list.add(value);
    cache.put(key, list);
}
```

is not needed as you already modify the object obtained from the cache. Maybe all you need is

```
public void add(Integer key, String value) {
    LinkedList<String> list = cache.get(key);
    synchronized (list) {
        list.add(value);
    }
}
```

It depends on what eviction happens. If there's no eviction at all, then it will work. If an entry can get evicted before the updating method finishes, then you're out of luck.

Nonetheless, there's a simple solution: Using a global lock would work, but obviously inefficiently. So use a list of locks:

```
private static final CONCURRENCY_LEVEL = 64; // must be power of two
List<Object> locks = Lists.newArrayList(); // an array would do as well
for (int i=0; i<CONCURRENCY_LEVEL; ++i) locks.add(new Object());

public void add(Integer key, String value) {
    synchronized (locks.get(hash(key))) {
        cache.get(key).add(value);
    }
}
```

where `hash`  - depending on the distribution of your keys - can be as simple as `key.intValue() & (CONCURRENCY_LEVEL-1)` or something like [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.hash%28int%29) what sort of randomizes the distribution.

---

While my above list of locks should work, there's `Striped.lock(int)` in Guava, which makes it a bit simpler and takes care of padding (see [false sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) for what it's good for) and whatever.

---

Most probably you should not use `LinkedList` as it's nearly always slower than `ArrayList`.

Comment: Isn't your use of the `synchronized` keyword just locking a local variable that only one thread (the thread that owns it) will use?

Comment: @maaartinus: Guava already has a convenient utility for your "list of locks" approach: [`Striped`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html).

Comment: My previous comment is based on incorrect info. I forgot that Java passes non-primitive objects by reference value.

Comment: @Exide To be exact, Java passes *everything* by value. This everything exists in two kinds: primitives and references. Most of the time we speak about objects, we mean references.

Comment: @maaartinus:  
But if eviction is enabled we should also synchronize on a key inside element removal/eviction logic(that is hidden inside guava logic), not only inside our add logic. I think that 
synchronized (locks.get(hash(key))) {
        cache.get(key).add(value);
} doesn't prevent the key from eviction, as result, we will receive npe since the key was evicted in a parallel thread.
 Pls correct me if I wrong.

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack I don't think you can get an NPE as with `cache.get(key)` you can't get `null`. The worst possible thing is AFAICT that you get and update an entry, which gets evicted in the meantime, so your update gets lost. This could easily happen with `expireAfterWrite` as you don't write the entry back (but there's no reason for using `expireAfterWrite` then), I guess, it can happen with every eviction policy, it's just pretty improbable. You could probably add some logic to `CacheLoader#load`, which would prevent this, but it can get complicated.